# github, binary file not shown

Tags: git, github

I'm following a course with "codewithmosh", and I'm following the "pull request", where I need to be able to see a file in "files changed", but it shows "binary file not shown", and when clicking it, it shows these ??? characters.

[image]

The file is saved in UTF-8, and I added on .gitattributes, that the .txt file should be treaded as a text.
But it doesn't seem to work

[image]

Comment: The attribute will work fine in git, I would suppose, but getting a provider to show it is a completely different story... I do not think a provider will go through `.gitattributes` to know how to deal with a file that looks like it's binary (`UTF-8` being the culprit, of course). Welcome to SO, ny the way!

Comment: What are the _actual_ contents of the file?

Comment: what u mean with content? excuse me, my english isn't the best!

Comment: @Catalina What’s inside the file? What _exact_ bytes does it contain? It sure doesn’t look like it’s `Hello` in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Your file isn't saved in UTF-8.  It appears that instead, your file is saved in UTF-16, which is an encoding unfortunately common on Windows and in some programming languages, but which is typically otherwise obsolete in favour of UTF-8, which has many advantages and no downsides compared to UTF-16.

For ASCII text, UTF-16 stores each character as two bytes, one of which is a NUL (zero) byte.  This makes Git think your data is binary.  All of the � symbols except the first two are NUL bytes and the first two are bytes 0xff and 0xfe, which make up the BOM, or byte order mark, which indicates whether the data is big-endian or little-endian.

In general, you should simply configure your editor and tools to always save files as UTF-8 *without* a BOM (byte-order mark).  If you do that, things will work out much better for you.  Even most Windows programs understand how to do that; the directions to do so depend on your editor.  If you're using Powershell commands on Windows to write text directly to files, don't do that; use Git Bash instead.

Once you've done that, you can commit and push it, and your file will appear correctly on GitHub.

If you really have a totally broken and incapable editor that cannot handle anything but UTF-16, then you need to adjust the `.gitattributes` file like so:

```
*.txt text working-tree-encoding=UTF-16LE-BOM
```

and then run `git add --renormalize .` before committing.  Then, Git will store files in the repository as UTF-8, but turn them into a Windows-compatible UTF-16 variant before checking them out in the working tree.  That will also fix things on GitHub.

Note that your project will effectively become Windows-only at that point, because users on macOS, Linux, and other Unix systems will not want to use UTF-16, especially the nonstandard Windows variant.

Comment: I understand, I also couldn't find a answer about this .gitattributes.
I want to always have it in my global, just like I have git config.
How do I do that?
Or  must I always start with "git  init" in every new file I'm working in?

Comment: I'm sooooooooooo happy! using git bash to add stuff to my files ARE WORKING like MAGIC!!!!!!

Thank you sooo so so so much! coz this was so much headache!

Comment: The `.gitattributes` files are per-repository.  There is a per-user configuration (see `git help gitattributes`), but it doesn't get shipped with the repository, so GitHub won't honour it because it won't know about it.